# Discrepancy in the number of layers using torchlop for yolov5s

Tags: pytorch, torch, yolov5

I am trying to load the yolov5s model from ultralytics and count the number of layers using torchlop. Here is the screenshot of the code :

[image: code]

if you see the number of layers in the output is 213 marked by a yellow line but in the csv file "yolov5s_profile.csv" there are only 125 rows. Please find screenshot below :[image: csv file]. Although the total number of parameters is same in the code output and csv file. So, what is reason for different number of layers?